# How to publish the Manage map server cache tile (Server) tool as an arcGis geoprocessing service?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, geoprocessing-service

I need to publish the  Manage map server cache tile on the arcgis server as a geoprocessing service. As a result I will be able to update the tiles of a tiled service through a service call.

I face 2 issues. 
Fistly, when analyzing it tells me that I need to copy the datasource to the server (datasouce is the published tiled service used to RUN the tool once so as to be able to publish it).

Second it tell me that staging fails

Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you need to publish it? I've never heard a good reason: this tool exists as a service already under the utilities folder I believe.

Comment: I need this so as to call it through http requests and update the cache when I have new data inserts. It is not the same as the one caching tools existing in the System folder of arcgis server manager if you mean that.

Comment: Pretty sure it's the same. The tool in desktop just makes a call to the server side tool.

Comment: Found it. Indeed it already exists in the system folder. I suppose That I cannot publish it since it is a system tool. Thanks @KHibma. Could you please answer the question so as to accept the answer ? It would be unfair to answer it on my own

Comment: See this post for utilizing the system cache services via REST:
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/205939/manage-map-cache-using-arcgis-server-10-4-rest-api-using-c-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caching tools that exist in the ArcToolbox on Desktop simply make calls to the Caching tools that have been already published on the Server.

If your workflow involves [updating a cache through these tools](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/automating-cache-creation-and-updates-with-geoprocessing.htm), simply call the tools on Desktop, or call the already published tools on the Server. Publishing these tools as their own GP Service introduces an extra execution within the workflow.

Comment: Indeed you can discover the service @KHibma told. However when I try to call it I am getting this error:  esriJobMessageTypeError: ERROR 001428: Failed to retrieve configuration for service http://go-infra.eurodyn.com:6080/arcgis/rest/services/allTiled/MapServer.
esriJobMessageTypeError: Failed to execute (Manage Map Cache Tiles).   Has anyone tried to call it?